# Wrap first three words in a span

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to filter the_content to wrap the first three words of the first paragraph in a span tag. This is my code so far:

```
function first_paragraph($content) {
   if(is_single()) {
      return preg_replace('regex goes here', "<p><span>$1</span>", $content, 1);
   }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'first_paragraph');
```

So far I didn´t found any regex and replacement that matches the first three words of the first paragraph.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like, this:

```
php > $content = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
php > echo preg_replace('/^((\S+\s+){2}\S+)/', '<span>$1</span>', $content);
<span>The quick brown</span> fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

So, you would want this:

```
function first_paragraph($content) {
   if(is_single()) {
      return preg_replace('/^((\S+\s+){2}\S+)/', "<p><span>$1</span>", $content, 1);
   }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'first_paragraph');
```

Just keep in mind that if the `$content` has less than four words, the regular expression won't match and the replacement won't happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it's not working properly. It works fine with your example, but it's not working for a content wrapped in <p> tags like the one that the_content() outputs :(

Comment: Exactly what is it doing?  Perhaps if you can provide an example value for `$content`, I can provide you a working solution.

Comment: Hey dossy! The output is a normal paragraph, like this:
<p>Some cool text goes here.</p>
Thanks!

Comment: @FriedSmurf - right, so `$content = '<p>Some cool text goes here.</p>';` and `echo preg_replace('/^((\S+\s+){2}\S+)/', '<span>$1</span>', $content);` outputs `<span><p>Some cool text</span> goes here.</p>` - yeah, this really isn't a good task for regular expressions.